# Prestashop - realize cart created on external site by webservice

Tags: web-services, api, prestashop, cart

Im using Prestashop webservice to manage cart on external site. I can create/update/delete cart and products by API, all works fine. My next step is add "realize" button, which redirect to the main shop, where user will by able to realize that cart. How can I created cart on external site show on shop? It is possible?

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a project simulair to what you're asking but i'm still struggling with the cart functionality, so add. update and delete etc. Could you maybe help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cart using webservices and add products to it. The problem is that when you redirect client to shop, even if this cart already exist in DB, shop cookies must be set and inside this encrypted Prestashop cookie should be the cart ID. So, I think you won't be able to do that.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the point. Maybe is not a perfect solution, but found the way, how to display cart created by webserice on external site.

By webservice, I created cart and order for temporary user. In history order of that user is link "reorder", whitch looks like:
http://your_presta_shop/zamowienie?submitReorder=&id_order=X

If you copy and paste that link on the any browser, you see your cart created by API.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but hope it helps someone.

There's a way to recover a cart (tested on 1.6.18). You can use the following URL:

> http://(your_shop)/order?step=3&recover_cart=(id_cart)&token_cart=(token)

- `id_cart` is the id of your cart :)
- `token` is calculated as follows: `md5(_COOKIE_KEY_.'recover_cart_'.$id_cart);` (`_COOKIE_KEY` comes from your config/settings.inc.php in your PrestaShop installation)

You can see that this URL is generated in this two files (not very DRY):

- `controllers/admin/AdminCartsController.php` (look for `recover_cart`)
- `controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php` (look for `recover_cart`)